Translating the deprecated gitlab ci "only" into "rules"
I have a lot of pipelines where I build things, and then the deployment runs on releases and is triggerd by a pipeline trigger. So to only run build/test jobs when pushing to gitlab, I have this:
job:
  only:
    refs:
      - branches

But according to Gitlab's CI/CD YAML syntax reference , only and except are deprecated, so I am trying to figure out how to do the same with rules.
After a deep read of the rules possibility, I am down to these two possibilities:
job:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

or
job:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push' && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

But I don't really understand which would be better, and which is the correct translation. I asked a few llms, and their answers were confusing at best.

Sounds like you want the 1st one. The second will trigger only on push, not on MR nor on manual trigger I think. In doubt, just try on a dummy project the conditions to see if it matche your needs

The following block means when the Git reference for a pipeline is a branch. It will be triggered when calling via api (instead of push), and also scheduled pipelines too.
job:
  only:
    refs:
      - branches

so it is more than push (api call, scheduled pipelines, etc). Therefore the correct translation will be
job:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH


You can use the following to achieve the same result:
job:
   rules:
     - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event")

or
job:
   rules:
     - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push")

